# Creation of node in graph results in nullpointer exception

Tags: java, graph

#
I'm a beginner in java, and I'm trying to implement a Graph data structure. I might've done a strange implementation, but I think it should work, I'm unsure as to why there is an error within the createNode method in my Graph class. I think someObject has a null reference, but I don't no how to handle my error. I THINK the rest of my code works, but I can't be sure, as I can't test it past this point. My code compiles, but when I try to create a Node from within my Graph class, I get a NullPointerError. I've tried a lot of things but none of them work. Before, I was trying to dynamically name my objects as they are created, but apparently Java doesn't support that feature, so I resorted to instantiating the object and storing them in a HashMap along with a string Key value.

My Main Class

```
public class GraphTraversal{

    public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            Graph marvelUniverse = new Graph();
            marvelUniverse.createNode("Princess Leia");
            marvelUniverse.createNode("Luke Skywalker");
            marvelUniverse.nodeJoin("Princess Leia", "Luke Skywalker", "A beautiful friendship");
            System.out.println(marvelUniverse.isAdjacent("Princess Leia", "Luke Skywalker"));
        }
}
```

My Node Class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Node
{
    protected String name;
    private HashMap<String,String> references;

    public Node(String character){
        this.name = character;
        this.references = new HashMap<String,String>();
        //HashMap<String, String> references = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void addRef(Node node, String edge){
        if (refExists(node)){
            if ((references.get(node.name)).compareTo(edge) >= 0){
            references.put(node.name, edge);
            }
            else 
                return;
        }
        else{
            references.put(node.name, edge);
            return;
        }
    }

    public boolean refExists(Node nodeName){
        if (references.get(nodeName.name) != null){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Graph Class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Graph
    {

    private HashMap<String, Node> nodeList;
    private ArrayList<String> objNames;
    public int count=0;

    public Graph(){
        HashMap<String, Node> nodeList = new HashMap<String, Node>();
        // List<String[]> objNames = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        // for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        //  objNames.add(("objectnames"+i));
        }

    public void createNode(String nodeName){
        //if (this.nodeExists(nodeName)==false){
            Node someObject;
            someObject = new Node(nodeName);
            nodeList.put(nodeName, someObject);
        //  }
    }

    public boolean isAdjacent(String firstNode, String secondNode){
        if ((nodeList.get(firstNode)).refExists(nodeList.get(secondNode))){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }   

    public void nodeJoin(String firstNode, String secondNode, String edge){
        if (isAdjacent(firstNode, secondNode) != true){
            (nodeList.get(firstNode)).addRef((nodeList.get(secondNode)),edge);
            (nodeList.get(secondNode)).addRef((nodeList.get(firstNode)),edge);
        }
        return;
    }

/*  public void listRefs(String someNode){
        (nodeList.get(someNode)).retRefs();
    } */

    public boolean nodeExists(String nodeName){
        // if(nodeList.get(nodeName)!=null){
        //  return true;
        // }
        return false;
    }

    //public void stringToGraph()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to programming, what's a stack trace? Do you mean:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Graph.createNode (Graph.java:24)
at GraphTraversal.main(GraphTraversal.java:6)

Comment: If you're using any modern Java IDE, you can run in debug mode. In debug mode, Eclipse will automatically break when it encounters and unhandled exception and that will let you look at the variables to see what is null.

Also, posting a stack trace can help. The stack trace is included in the error message that tells you there's an exception (maybe just paste all output on the commandline).

Comment: You would be seeing a complete line telling you where exactly the nullpointerException is. If you are using an IDE e.g. eclipse then you can easily copy from there and paste here

Comment: @user3010969 : Exactly

Comment: Ah, I was only using a text editor and command line compilation. But when I used eclipse, I think it said that someObject holds a null reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see it closely, you have only declared NodeList not initialized it any where :

```
private HashMap<String, Node> nodeList;
```

You need to make it like

```
private HashMap<String, Node> nodeList = new HashMap();
```

Alternatively, you can change your local variable in the constructor and update the nodeList variable of Graph object:

```
public Graph(){
    this.nodeList = new HashMap<String, Node>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now, but could you explain to me what's the difference with what you've listed as solutions and what I've done? Did I create a local variable in my constructor that's separate from the private HashMap<String, Node> nodeList; I declared above?

Comment: Yes, In your constructor you created and initialized a local variable. But in createNode method you were trying to use class variable nodeList which was only declared not initialized. Would suggest you to use in IDE e.g Eclipse or Netbeans. Will give a great advantage while learning

Comment: If you're interested in learning about exactly why this solution fixed it, read up on scopes in java.  Understanding them is essential whether you use an IDE or not.  A quick search turned up this to get you started http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html